# Matrix GLM estimation Example Explanation

Tags: self-study, anova, generalized-linear-model, matrix, eigenvalues

> **Below is my question:

It is an example from the book " A Primer on linear modes" by Monahan**

[image]
I have  3 questions

> Question 1:

is how did he calculated the matrix λ

> Question 2:

Why  $λ $  it is not in  $C $( $X^T$)

> Question 3:

How do we know that specifically $α_1 $  is non-estimable and not $a_2$